# engine will not start

Tags: spark

so me and a freind built a very identical single cylander bicycle engine kit and no matter what we have possible tried we can not get his to start (not even fire or pop once). so i got mine running and it works fine and they are the same engine. but we have tried and tested everyting. Hes got gas, air, compression, and spark when we tested it by holding it on the outside of the cylander. everything seems to be perfect..... after a whole day of trying to start it ajusting everything with still no pop at all.... the only thing we can possibly think it is is that for some reason the spark plug is not sparking when its in the cylander if that is a thing?! please help.. we havetried litterly everything and had many people look at it and they are baffeled as well... help (the engine is just a little 66cc two stroke bike kit)

Comment: Have you checked the timing?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle you're working on?